# working with large string

Tags: c#, string, performance, optimization

I am working with a large string in C#. For example, my string length is 2.000.000 characters. I have to encrypt this string. I have to save it as a text file on a hard disk. I've tried to encrypt by using XOR for the fastest and basic text encryption but still takes too long encryption. It takes 1 hour with 2.13 GHz duo cpu and 3 GB RAM. Also, saving the file (using StreamWriter Write method) and reading from the file (using StreamReader ReadToEnd method) takes too long.

The code:

```
public static string XorText(string text) 
{   
   string newText = ""; 
   int key = 1; 
   int charValue; 
   for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) 
   {
     charValue = Convert.ToInt32(text[i]); //get the ASCII value of the character 
     charValue ^= key; //xor the value 
     newText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue); //convert back to string 
   } 
   return newText; 
}
```

What is your advice for these operations?

Comment: So you want to encrypt a text file?

Comment: Why do you call ConvertFromUtf32? I mean, it's not as if you're calling ConvertToUtf32 first. So that one can go too.

Comment: Why even go through text at all? Just XOR the bytes?

Comment: Your string is barely 2 MB in size. No way this is taking up 3 GB of RAM. And done right this should only take seconds. There’s something else going on which you aren’t telling us.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of string for large strings, also is better to show your code to see if any other optimization is possible. e.g for reading/writing from/into files you can use buffers.

**Update:** As I can see in your code biggest problem (with this code) is in this line:

```
newText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
```

`String` is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) object, and by `+=` operator every time you will create a new instance of `newText` and when the length is big this causes to time and memory problems, so instead of `string` if you use `StringBuilder` this line of code will be as this:

```
newText.Append(char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue));
```

and this function will be run extremely faster.

Comment: @user1400531, See my update and it was better to do not delete your comment to keep history of your updated code.

Comment: Yes, `+=` is a problem; it creates a new string every time, so that would create 2,000,000 new strings in total. But I'm not sure if that's the only bottleneck. Does creating 2,000,000 strings take an hour on a 2GHz machine?

Comment: @MrLister, I think this causes to memory problems and garbage collector doesn't work properly in this case, Also yes this is not the only buttleneck in the system, there are some other buttlenecks like `Convert.ToInt32(text[i]);` or `char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);` but I think `+=` is biggest issue here.